# Eddy Current Pendulum and Variables of Breaking Force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I am trying to conduct an experiment about eddy currents, specifically using an aluminum plate pendulum, two permanent magnets, high framerate camera. I am altering the distance between the two permanent magnetic poles, thereby altering the magnetic field strength, and measuring the retarding force on the pendulum with the camera.

My setup is kind of like a waltenhofen pendulum, however, I was wondering if I need to control the current supplied in the magnets.

I do not have a full understanding of this concept, so I would like to know the main variables that would affect the retarding force and how the force could be calculated. Possibly a crude equation with assumptions made.

I would appreciate any help.